# FPDF getPageWidth / getPageHeight returning incorrect values

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to split a multi page PDF into single PDF files, and the source PDF is not standard PDF size.

From the constructor of FPDF I can pass width/height, and I can get these values from another instance of FDPF. However the values returned by these methods are not as I expect:

```
$pdf = new Fpdi("P", "mm");
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($sourcePath); // How many pages?
$pageWidth = $pdf->GetPageWidth();
$pageHeight = $pdf->GetPageHeight();
```

return values:

`$pageWidth = 210.00155555556`

`$pageHeight = 297.00008333333`

The values I expect are: `300 × 440 mm` as I see them in the `Document` properties menu of my system File Reader: [image]

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: You create an `Fpdi` object with default page size, which is A4. Hence the values.

Comment: Can you recommend a way to find the page size of a PDF before constructing Fpdi?

Comment: You could use something like [this](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/) to analyze an existing PDF.